# Design of electronic lock

Tags: voltage, diodes, analog

I am designing a electronic lock using a electromagnet(coil).This is my circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8n1qS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When the switch is closed it will short the circuit and current will stop flowing the inductor-> the lock will open.

I was wondering if I should add a diode in series with the inductor just like this for protection:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZ3le8.png)</sup>

in order to prevent any significant current flow in the opposite direction in case a voltage opposite to the battery is induced somehow and damage the battery and generally to block any voltages opposite to the battery.

Should I do it?

Comment: Then circuit disconnected, energy , saved in inductor need to be released. Current is going in reverse and may damage the circuit. Usually flyback diode in parallel with inductor, reversed polarity, used. Resistor is not essential, switch in series should be connected.

Comment: Wouldn't the energy stored in the inductor be released through the diode in my circuit?

Comment: Your circuit doesn't let any current flow in the inductor because the diode blocks it.

Comment: Yeah my bad corrected it.

Comment: Diode should be parallel to the coil, but opposite direction.

Comment: The intent is for the lock to also open when there is no power, right?

Comment: Why would you not use a normally closed (NC) pushbutton in series with the supply?

Comment: Just so you know this type of lock is not particularly difficult to defeat.  Even the commercial door version can be forced without a lever by about 6 people (although prisons may get a better model than my university residence did.  With a wedge and hammer and/or lever they can be popped fairly easily, so if you're building a small version, be aware of that.  A well designed lip will prevent use of a chisel and make it difficult to pry.  Be careful how you design your magnet shroud and plate as the slightest airgap greatly decreases the hold power.

Comment: Constant use of power and security loss on power loss are the other obvious disadvantages.  A solenoid driven pin arrangement may be better if you're running on batteries or security is actually a factor.  If you just want a super cool box, you're definitely on the right track, but if you're OK with having it lock slower you can use a magnet with more turns and finer wire and save some power.

Answer (score 2):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLWMAs.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. A more straight-forward circuit construction.*

The fact that you've got a permanent magnet suggests that your lock should be held by magnet and **released** by the electromagnet. This is the system that is used in prison locks so you need to consider whether or not this is safe if the lock can not be released due to power failure.

[image]

*Figure 1. A commercial maglock. (Sorry, image source lost.)*

I don't know this, but I suspect that for either a power-to-lock or a power-to-release type that three poles are arranged as south-north-south (or vice-versa) and that the coil is wound, pushed into the black slots and potted in position. Once the (electro) magnet hits the keeper the magnetic circuit is closed. As anyone who has played with a horseshoe magnet will know, opening the closed loop is very difficult.

[image]

*Figure 2. The maglock is an open and shut case. (Illustration mine.)*

Here we can see that with the lock open the exposed faces are poles of the magnet. Note also that the magnetic path is twice as wide in the centre pole as on the upper and lower poles so that flux density is fairly constant. Once the lock closes the flux forms a loop through the iron core.

The energise-to-lock type requires power to create the magnetic field. The energise-to-release type requires the electro-magnet to cancel the field of the permanent magnet.

Comment: The circuit you have posted needs a resistance and anyway I want when to press the button the lock gets unlocked.

Comment: 1. Why do you think a resistance is required? 2. My circuit is a normally closed pushbutton. It switches off the electro magnetic when pressed. That seems to be what you are asking for.

Comment: When the switch is closed you don't have any resistance to reduce current.

Comment: Why do you need to reduce current unless your coil voltage rating is wrong for the supply you are using?

Comment: The coil winding has resistance. You choose the gauge of wire and number of turns to give the required resistance so that the required current flows. External resistors would be a waste of power and that's why you don't see them in maglocks, solenoids or relay coils.

Answer (score 0):

To suppress the inductive kick caused by removing current from the inductor, a diode needs to be in parallel with the coil, not in series.  In your drawing, cathode toward R2.

To prevent an induced current from harming the battery, a second diode needs to be in parallel with the battery.  This should be a zener diode.  The problem is that you do not know the polarity of the induced current, so you have to protect the battery from both.  A zener diode with a zener voltage that is greater than V1 can do this.  Cathode toward toward V1+.

Answer (score 0):

Since AnalogKid explained the diode sufficiently, let's consider the other aspects of the circuit.

You should consider the various ways in which the arrangement of coil and permanent magnet could be changed.

Presently, the coil must always be powered to keep the lock closed, and shorting the coil out will unlock it, but it will consume even more power while the button is pressed.

What if you added a spring or rubber band, to keep the magnet in some default position *without* the coil being powered? Call that the "locked" state. Is there then some way to cause the coil to unlock this? If you can design such a system, it will use *zero* power while locked, and only consume power while the button is pressed.

Comment: I don't think the system you propose is possible.

Comment: See [this example](https://protosupplies.com/product/solenoid-electric-door-lock-12v-0-9a/). Instead of a magnet, this uses a piece of metal, so is called a solenoid. Same rules with a diode apply. But see how the spring keeps it popped out (and locked) until the coil activation pulls it in?

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score -3):

After many answers I decided to add a diode  parallel to the the inductor and use pushbutton(normally closed) just like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fA30HS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Thanks everyone for your help!

Comment: (1) Your schematic has no pushbutton switch. (2) The diodes short out the solenoid. You will have a maximum of 0.7 V available to L1-R3. (3) You haven't explained why you think you need 300 ohms in series with the magnet coil. (4) This is most unlikely to work.

Comment: I don't think the diodes short anything.They are just in case the voltage kick from the inductor is too big.

Comment: Then you don't know how diodes work. If the voltage across L1-R3 rises above 0.6 or 0.7 V D1 will be forward biased and almost all the current will flow through it. You will have 0.7 V across L1-R3. Hit the *Simulate* link below your schematic and run the DC solver, measuring the voltages at each end of D1 and subtract the lower from the higher to calculate the voltage difference.

Comment: maybe i should lower the resistances a little bit.

Comment: Why? That will make the diode problem worse as more current will flow through D1 and you haven't explained why the resistors are there in the first place.

Comment: The resistors are there to reduce current flowing through the inductor.But now I see it better i am not sure i need at least 2 of them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121289/discussion-between-transistor-and-miss-mulan).